# Cursor pagination with Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm looking for some manageable ways to handle pagination using the requests library in Python. I want my `_request` method to be able to handle single page and indefinite page requests alike.

Here is my `_request` method:

```
def _request(self, url, params={}, headers={}):
    if self.app_access_token:
        headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {self.app_access_token}"
    headers["Client-ID"] = self.client_id

    try:
        response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
        response_json = response.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during _request: {e}")

    if response.status_code == 429:
        self._authenticate_application()
        self._request(url, params=params, headers=headers)

    if "cursor" in response_json["pagination"]:
        params["after"] = response_json["pagination"]["cursor"]

    return data
```

Here is a cursor example:

```
    ...
   ],
   "pagination": {
     "cursor": "eyJiIjp7Ik9mZnNldCI6MH0sImEiOnsiT2Zmc2V0Ijo0MH19"
   }
```

My initial thought was to make another request after with the `after` param if the key `cursor` was present (when there are no more pages, `pagination` will not contain `cursor`), but this will only suffice for 2 pages.

What are some ways that I can persist the data from the original request to continue making requests until there are no more pages then return the data?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the solution in your code. If the response code is 429, you re-call the `self._request`  method. You can do the same for the pagination and yield the data.

```
def _request(self, url, params={}, headers={}):
    ...

    if "cursor" in response_json["pagination"]:
        params["after"] = response_json["pagination"]["cursor"]
        self._request(url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I haven't touched `yield` really at all yet, but I suspected that may be what I was looking for. If I do `yield` the data, will it essentially append until I return? Would you mind showing me an example?